# How do I handle user stories and burn down charts?

Tags: scrum, testing

I am new to Scrum. I've done some searches; However, I failed to find answers for the following questions:

- When should we mark a user story as completed in a burn down? Do we do this when the development is completed or when it's through QA?
- If a task fails in QA, should we add it as a new user story or update the task hours?
- If the team asks for extra hours to fix the bugs due to some complexity, how can I update the total time remaining?

Comment: While some of these questions are closely related, others are really separate questions. Please ask only a single question within a post. You can edit this question to contain only a single question, and then ask others in separate posts if you still need to do so.

Answer (score 5):

> When should we mark a user story as completed in a burn down? Do we do this when the development is completed or when it goes through QA?

The team commits to creating a 'potential shippable increment' at the end of a sprint. So, the story should be ready to ship in all respects.

> If a task fails in QA, should we add it as a new user story or update
>   the task hours?

The team gets no credit for stories that are not complete in all respects by the end of the sprint. Add a new user story in the backlog, estimate it and let the Product Owner prioritize it.

> If the team asks extra hours to fix the bugs due to some complexity,
>   how can I update the total time remaining?

Hours remaining to complete tasks can be estimated at any time for internal tracking purposes regardless of what the original estimate was and how many hours have been already spent.

Looks like your team will benefit from some Scrum training followed by an internal team discussion of "Definition of done".

Answer (score 1):

> When should we mark a user story as completed in a burn down? Do we do this when the development is completed or when it's through QA?

Your definition of "done" should answer to this question but you should consider that if there is anything left to do for a story it is not "done" thus not burned. The idea behind burndown is to see how much work left to do for the "potentially shippable" product.

> If a task fails in QA, should we add it as a new user story or update the task hours?

QA should be part of your definition of "done", so any task that does not fulfill the "done" requirements gets updated its work remaining and be sent to appropriate step.

> If the team asks for extra hours to fix the bugs due to some complexity, how can I update the total time remaining?

As @Ashok said in his post, you can update remaining time at any point.